# C++ Int doesn't seem to be initializing and Exception thrown: read access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2015, memory-leaks

I'm very new to C++ so please excuse the sloppy code.
Here is the code in question:

Bag Class

```
class Bag {
protected:
    Item* _myItems;
    int _numItems;
    int _size;
public:
    Bag();
    Bag(int size);
    ~Bag();
    Bag(Bag& original);
    void add(Item a);
    void remove(int itemnum);
    int size();
    int numItems();
    void operator=(Bag& bag);
    Item& operator[] (int i);
};

//Empty constructor
Bag::Bag() {
    _numItems = 0;
}

//overloaded constructor
Bag::Bag(int size) {
    _numItems = 0;
    _myItems = new Item[size];
}

//copy constructor
Bag::Bag(Bag& original) {
    //Copies the numItems
    _numItems = original._numItems;
    //Makes a new copy of the original array
    _myItems = new Item[_numItems];
    //Copies each element of the original into the new
    for (int i = 0; i < _numItems; ++i) {
        _myItems[i] = original[i];
    }
}

//Destructor
Bag::~Bag(){
    delete[] _myItems;
}

//Returns the size of the bag
int Bag::size()
{
    return _size;
}

//Returns the number of items in the bag
int Bag::numItems() {
    return _numItems;
}

//Add a new item to the bag
void Bag::add(Item a) {
    int s = _numItems;
    //Create a Item pointer and assign it to the array of the bag
    Item* temp = _myItems;
    //Assign _myItems to a new, larger array
    _myItems = new Item[_numItems++];
    //Copy the old array into the new one and nullify all the old array's items
    for (int i = 0; i < _numItems - 1; i++) { 
        _myItems[i] = temp[i];  
    }
    //Destroy the old array
    delete[] temp;
    //Add the item to the last position
    _myItems[_numItems] = a;
}
```

I am reading a text file line by line. The reading seems to be happening just fine. When I read in I execute this part of the code:

```
//The main program
int main() {

    Pens * onePen = new Pens(1, 2);
    Pens * twoPen = new Pens(2, 3);

    Bag* bag = new Bag(5);

    (*bag).add(onePen);
    (*bag).add(twoPen);

    bag[0];
    bag[1];

    int d = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the Read Access Violation (This was 0xc) when I get into the add method. I also notice that when I put in breakpoints to examine the code, _numItems is not 0 but 211. Am I corrupting my memory somehow?

[Here is a sample text file that we are using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7bey_CDNVt9RVAtT29WMkY0Q00/view?usp=sharing)

Simplified version of the Bag and Pen classes (courtesy of PaulMcKenzie):

```
class Item {
protected:
    int code_;

    //Sets the method definition for the get/set methods and constructors
public:
    Item(int code = -1);
    virtual ~Item() {}
    int getcode() const;
    void setcode(int code);
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s);
    bool operator== (const Item& a) const;
};

Item::Item(int code) : code_(code) {}
int Item::getcode() const { return code_; }
void Item::setcode(int code) { code_ = code; }

std::ostream & Item::operator<<(std::ostream& s)
{
    s << " Code - " << code_ << "\n";
    return s;
}

bool Item::operator==(const Item & a) const
{
    return (code_ == a.getcode());
}

class Pens : public Item
{
private: int packetsize_;
public:
    Pens();
    Pens(int code, int packetsize);
    int getpacketsize() const;
    void setpacketsize(int packetsize);
    bool operator== (const Pens& a) const;
};

Pens::Pens() :Item() { }
Pens::Pens(int code, int packetsize) : Item(code), packetsize_(packetsize) {}
int Pens::getpacketsize() const { return packetsize_; }
void Pens::setpacketsize(int packetsize) { packetsize_ = packetsize; }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Pens& pen)
{
    s << " Packet size: " << pen.getpacketsize() << "\n";
    return s;
}

bool Pens::operator==(const Pens & a) const
{
    return code_ == a.getcode() && packetsize_ == a.getpacketsize();
}
```

Comment: To answer the question you asked, exactly: yes, you are corrupting memory. I see at least two different places which corrupt memory. Free clue #1, what will the destructor `delete[]`, if the object was default-constructed? Free clue #2: if when `add()` is called `numItems_` was, say, 2, and `myItems_` was, presumably, an array of two values, how big will be the new, replacement `myItems_` array that `add()` new-s in there? Free clue #3: no, the new array will not contain 3 values.

Comment: The following program produces a problem: `{Bag b;}`.  The reason is that you failed to initialize the member pointer in your default constructor, and the destructor is calling `delete[]` on an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Another issue is that you're calling `add()` using a different `Item` type, and you're passing `Item` by value.  This creates a condition called *object slicing*.  The code has many problems with it -- why as a beginner to C++ are you trying to write code that only an intermediate to advanced C++ programmer should even attempt?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is for a Data Structures class. They basically jumped from Java, which was used last semester in the prerequisite class, to C++ in this course. The Instructor gives us C++ projects. We covered more data structure concepts in the class than how C++ works...

Comment: @DavidNettey - The issue with using C++ to implement data structures is that there are two hurdles to climb -- the first is the C++ language itself, the second being the implementation of the data structure.  With Java, you don't have the "langiuage roadblock" as you have no pointers, objects are garbage collected, etc.  The problem is that you really need to be an intermediate to advanced C++ programmer *first* before implementing the data structure.  There is no way (or very little chance) a beginner will implement this correctly in C++.

Comment: @DavidNettey -- [Continuing] So basically, unless someone goes in and does a rewrite of what you've done and posted it as an answer, that is the only way to really go forward.  Don't know if that is what you expected.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, I'm finding out how different this is from Java first hand haha. The point of the project I think is to illustrate how to use Arrays within classes as a data structure. I'm not really expecting a complete solution to the Project. Its just that I keep running into all sorts of issues due to my inexperience with dealing with pointers, destructors, etc. I got the add method to work somewhat. But now when the command "DelItem" is read in, the loop completely bypasses my if statements. :(

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For reference the txt file is structured like this: AddItem 1323 221 3 1 1 4 7.75 7.62 0.69 0.025 4.97 2 0 8
AddItem 1534 201 2 1 4 2 7.75 7.62 0.69 0.025 11.99 1 0 12
AddItem 1534 202 2 1 2 2 7.75 7.62 0.69 0.025 11.99 1 0 12
DelItem 1323 221
AddItem 1776 253 1 1 3 1 7.75 7.62 0.69 0.025 10.00 4 0 1
AddItem 1323 253 1 1 3 1 7.75 7.62 0.69 0.025 10.00 4 0 1
AddItem 1776 281 2 1 4 1 7.75 7.62 0.69 0.025 10.67 3 1 3

Comment: You need to post any additional information in the question itself, not in the comment section.  Second, you need to post what `Item` is.  But to the bigger point -- unless all the errors are corrected (not just a few here and there), the code will not run correctly.  How you get the input is the least of your concerns, believe me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just posted a link to a Pastebin holding my source file and a link to the text file. The instructions are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7bey_CDNVt9elB1UHhBNWRmTVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DavidNettey -- The issue with pastebin links is that 1) Not everyone can get to them, and most importantly 2) the link isn't permanent, making the question meaningless if the link goes away.  You should post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the information. Didn't know that pastebin was only temporary. I'll try to simplify the code as much as possible and edit the question with it.

Comment: @DavidNettey -- [Here is a small sample of a stripped down version](http://ideone.com/NDa235).  This shows that `Items` only needs a few functions and that all you need is to derive just one small class from it.  You don't need an assignment operator, and you don't need all of those member variables (the assignment operator is not necessary, as the compiler's default will work just fine).

Comment: @DavidNettey -- With all of this, the major issue I see is that you're using Java object behavior in a C++ program.  In your `Bag::add` function, you're passing `Item` by value.  This may work find and dandy in Java, but is a disaster in C++ since your `Bag` class is storing a sliced object.  Your `Bag::_myItems` can only store `Item` types, not `Pen`, `Printer`, etc. types.  When you get to lines like this: `_myItems[_numItems] = a;` -- you're trying to stuff 10 pounds of potatoes into a 5 pound bag.  This is called *object slicing* -- please do a search on this topic.

Comment: If you want to store all of those types, then your best bet is to store `Item *`, and not `Item`.  This means that you pass the address of the item to store, not the item itself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see! Should I try implementing the bag class and main method using your stripped down version?

Comment: Yes you can try the stripped down version, since the main problem with the code is not exhibited using what I removed.  It is basically just a class, a derived class, and you're storing both types in one container.  All you need to do is just add two items to your Bag class to see the issue (no need for `cin` or anything, just two calls to `add()` to introduce the undefined behavior).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think I'll stop here for tonight and work on this tomorrow. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DavidNettey If you look at the answer given by Boris, you can see that calling `add()` twice causes an issue. When testing a data structure, there is no  need to clutter the testing program with `cin` and complex input routines.  Just call the functions exposed by your data structure with dummy data to see how it behaves.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand, I probably should have been testing it with a super simple version like the one I provided as I was writing up the code. Anyways, I changed that like so that it reads _myItems = new Item*[++_numItems]; and changed the last line to _myItems[_numItems - 1] = a and it seemed to add the first item. However It doesn't seem to make the array bigger when I go to add the second item.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As for the object slicing, if I'm understanding this correctly, when I pass an object derived from Item into something that only takes pure Items, it "slices off" anything that pertains to Item's derived classes leaving only things that have to do with Item itself right? So what I need to do is make _myItems an array of Item pointers rather than just straight up Items. That way it has nothing to slice.

Comment: You have `size` as a member variable, but it is not the same value as `numItems`.  Look at your `Bag` constructor that takes a size argument-- it sets numItems to 0, but allocates `size` items.  See the inconsistency?  When you call `add`, you assume that you need to reallocate when you really don't need to.  A dynamic array usually has two values, a `size` to denote the number of items actually in the array, and a "capacity" that determines the max number of items that can be added before a reallocation occurs.

Comment: See [this example](http://ideone.com/FNk5Tc) of a dynamic array class.  That's as much as I can do to help further, and that is to show an example of a working "bag" class (which is really a dynamic array).  It is templated, but the basics are still there (a `remove` wasn't coded -- that's another story -- you don't really need to deallocate the memory to remove an item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not look in depth but this segment caught my eye:

```
//Add a new item to the bag
void Bag::add(Item a) {
int s = _numItems;
//Create a Item pointer and assign it to the array of the bag
Item* temp = _myItems;
//Assign _myItems to a new, larger array
_myItems = new Item[_numItems++];
//Copy the old array into the new one and nullify all the old array's items
for (int i = 0; i < _numItems - 1; i++) { 
    _myItems[i] = temp[i];  
}
//Destroy the old array
delete[] temp;
//Add the item to the last position
_myItems[_numItems] = a;
}
```

Please look at this line:

```
_myItems = new Item[_numItems++];
```

You create new array with size of **_numItems** and *then* increase the **_numItems** by 1.

Which in my humble opinion leaves you with array of size **_numItems-1**.
And then you try to use element **_myItems[_numItems]** so this may be the reason of memory corruption.

Comment: I see! would calling it like this: _myItems = new Item[++_numItems]; change that?

Comment: Just tried it and changed the last like of the add method to _myItems[_numItems - 1] = a and it worked! However I can't seem to add another item..